# error add libraryDependencies "io.prediction"

Tags: scala, predictionio

good afternoon,
i would ask about error when i tried added libraryDependencies "io.prediction" here's my code

```
name := "SBTMaret2016"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += toGroupID("org.scalatest") % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test" (a)
libraryDependencies += toGroupID("io.prediction") %% "core" % "0.9.5" % "provided" (b)
libraryDependencies += toGroupID("org.apache.spark") %% "spark-core"  % "1.3.0" % "provided" (c)
libraryDependencies += toGroupID("org.apache.spark") %% "spark-mllib"  % "1.3.0" % "provided"(d)
```

first time, im add (a,c,d) and it work!
when im re-add (b) it doesn't work. any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prediction, there are no artifacts published for Scala 2.11. You can switch to 2.10.6 or try to get the source and compile it for 2.11. The Scalatest dependency is also incorrect; it should be `toGroupID("org.scalatest") %% "scalatest"`. (Plus, you can remove all `toGroupId` calls; the usual way to write this is `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core"  % "1.3.0" % "provided"`.)

Comment: did you mean, i must change scalaVersion into = 2.10?
is it necessary change **toGroupID** into **GroupId**?

Comment: 2.10.something (the latest is 2.10.6) and just replace e.g. `toGroupID("org.scalatest")` with `"org.scalatest"`.